# Would a radio wave at the same wavelength as Middle C be detectable around a corner the same way that sound is?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

So, if someone makes a sound, then another person can hear it around a corner. Does this mean that a radio wave with the same wavelength as such a sound is also detectable around the same corner?

Comment: This site may help: https://www.quora.com/2-Why-do-radio-waves-diffract-around-buildings-although-light-waves-do-not.

Comment: Note that one-meter radio wavelengths fall in the [ultra-high frequency (UHF) band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_high_frequency).

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are asking if a radio wave will diffract around corners the same way as acoustic waves. Several wavelengths away it is true but when you get within a wavelength of the diffracting object the details can be quite different because the EM waves are vectors, while an acoustic wave is a scalar wave. Note too that when we are talking about diffraction the significant physical quantity is not frequency of the wave but its wavelength relative to the geometric scale of the diffracting object. Since the frequency of the middle C is about 260Hz the acoustic wavelength is $\lambda_a \sim 330/260 \sim 1.2m$ while for a radio wave would be $\lambda_r \sim3 \times 10^8/260 \sim 1150km$, thousand times longer, so this RF wave encountering almost anything on the earth would penetrate easily well beyond the obstacle's shadow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did actually mean wavelength. I edited my question to reflect that.